# running cmake commands in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, boost, cmake

Is it possible to run cmake commands in a python script? I want to set the boost libraries which I installed and compiled manually through the python code.I want something like `set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/path/to/boost/include")` to happen via python script. So, before running cmake I want the cmake variables to set through the python code.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to launch Python as part of CMake processing your `CMakeLists.txt` and have that Python somehow set CMake variables in the currently running CMake?

Comment: No,before running `cmake` I want to set cmake variables through python script.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to make that more obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of pre-initialising CMake variables before CMake processing starts, both using [command-line arguments of `cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html).

The simple one is to pass one or more variables to CMake using the `-D` command-line option. Something like this:

```
cmake -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:PATH="/path/to/boost/include" ...
```

The other option is to create an "initial cache file" (basically a file containing just `set(...)` CMake commands) and pass that initial cache file to CMake using `-C`:

```
echo 'set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/path/to/boost/include" CACHE PATH "")' > initial_cache.cmake
cmake -C initial_cache.cmake ...
```

This option is intended for use the first time CMake is run with a given binary directory, i.e. *before* it creates its own `CMakeCache.txt` file.

How you can utilise one or both of these from your Python script depends on your particular setup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

## Option 1 (if you invoke cmake via python)

By setting cmake cache variables from the command line. The syntax for defining this from the command line is as follows from [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#opt:-Dvar:typevalue)

```
-D <var>:<type>=<value>
```

So in your case, in the cmake list file

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR MY_BOOST_INCLUDE)
```

Then simply override that option when invoking cmake

```
cmake -DMY_BOOST_INCLUDE:STRING="/path/to/wherever"
```

## Option 2 (if you want to invoke cmake at another point)

You can make a cmake module in python that sets the defines you want. For example, make a python script that populates `my_module.cmake` with any cache variables you want, i.e.

```
set(MY_BOOST_INCLUDE "script/generated/path")
#... other stuff you want to define
```

Then in your static cmake list file

```
include(my_module)
```

Comment: Option 2a) run CMake with `-C my_cache.cmake` to pre-load your generated file to populate cache.

Answer (score 0):

Some of CMake's [find modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) do support reading path hints from environment variables:

- > "Users may set these hints or results as cache entries. [...] One may specify these as environment variables if they are not specified as CMake variables or cache entries."
- I prefer this method of setting find module directories, because it's something I could also set on system level and I don't have to give every single of my CMake projects the paths to my custom build libraries anymore.
- [`FindBoost.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L1058) is an good example, because it offers various environment variable:

  ```
  Boost_DIR
  BOOSTROOT 
  BOOST_ROOT 
  BOOST_INCLUDEDIR 
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
  ```
- *Note*: Those are considered "hints", since they will not overwrite any CMake cache values once [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) was found.